Adding Kivy filechooser to a PopUp in Python
I have been trying to create a file chooser popup from a button release for an app.
I have managed a FileChooser, and Popups separately, but can't work out the two together, can anyone here help with a solution?
I am trying to implement the PopUp in Python instead of Kivy.lang as this is the experience I have with popups. I am unable to get the Kivy Doc example to work either.
The Code I have at the moment is below.
import kivy
from kivy.uix.filechooser import FileChooserListView
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
import os

Builder.load_string(
"""
<MyWidget>:
    
    Button
        text: "open"
        on_release: root.load()
""")
    

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    def load(self):
        
        load_popup = Popup(
            title = "Select logo",
            size_hint = (None, None),
            size = (500, 500)
        )
         
        file_load= FileChooserListView(
            on_selection = self.selected(file_load.selection) #selection not in My
        )
        content = file_load
        load_popup.content = content
        load_popup.open()
        

    def open(self, path, filename):
        with open(os.path.join(path, filename[0])) as f:
            print(f)

    def selected(self, filename):
        print("selected: %s" % filename[0])


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()


I get an error when running your code (file_load is used before assignment). But you can correct that by changing:
    file_load= FileChooserListView(
        on_selection = self.selected(file_load.selection) #selection not in My
    )

to:
    file_load = FileChooserListView(
        on_submit=self.selected
    )

then redefine your selected() method as:
def selected(self, chooser, filename, touch):
    print("selected: %s" % filename[0])


You are a Champion! Thank you So much. now I want to know why..... I will look into this.
